# How to create/update record if some variables are not set through strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Some of the variables are required for a record but not included in the params. How to then create/update such a record? Would the code below be correct? I belief the new method works, but have doubts about the update method.

**New record:**

```
connect = Connect.new(update_params(connection))
connect.first_id = comp1.id
connect.second_id = comp2.id
connect.save
```

**Update existing record:**

```
#If record exists, do this:
connect.first_id = comp1.id
connect.second_id = comp2.id
if connect.save
  unless connect.update_attributes(update_connection_params(connection))
    return render json: @organization, message: connect.errors.full_messages, status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write validations for these fields, on validation error(s) the record will not be saved and `save` will return `false`.

Common pattern is to render the form again, with errors, asking the user to correct

Your code for new record is correct, just check return value of `save` like for existing:

```
connect.assign_attributes update_connection_params(connection)
connect.first_id = comp1.id
connect.second_id = comp2.id
if connect.save
  redirect_to somewhere_path
else
  return render json: @organization, message: connect.errors.full_messages, status: :bad_request
end
```

Comment: Yes, I have the validations. But some of these required variables don't exist as parameters. That is, they are not send with form submission but are "calculated" on bases of other variables. So part of what is to be saved is included in the parameters and part of it is not. So these are not part of the `update_params` and `update_attributes(update_params)` therefore does not save them.

Comment: Or can I also include "calculated" variables in the strong params?

Comment: @Marty then regular setters in controller before save will do, see updated answer

Comment: That's great! Wasn't familiar with `assign_attributes`.